# How to pass arguments for bluebird callback in then()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a call that returns promise. At this moment, I do this:

```
Something( ... )
  .then(()=>{console.log("Done.");});
```

This would be more practical:

```
Something( ... )
  .then(console.log, "Done.");
```

For example, `setTimeout` works like that:

```
setTimeout(console.log, 1000, "Done.");
```

Does Bluebird have any method for this? My aim is to have this *practical* option to reduce the already ridiculous amount of code that Promises generate.

Comment: unfortunately it's part of the promise/A+ standard as you can see listed at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and at [this website](https://promisesaplus.com/) bluebird is just enforcing the rules, also you must have a callback returned from a promise resolve/reject which is why it must be a function whether it be anon empty or filled with data. --edit specifically with this bulletin [here](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-35)

Comment: "unfortunately it's part of the promise/A+ standard" I'd say **fortunately**. :) Otherwise each and every implementation would have slightly different sudden polymophic one "to reduce ridiculous amount of code blah-blah-blah"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At this moment, I do this:
>
> ```
> Something(…).then(()=>{console.log("Done.");});
> ```

This is the correct approach. Arrow functions already shorten this a lot. Notice that you can drop the "`{`"…"`;}`" parts.

> This would be more practical:
>
> ```
> Something(…).then(console.log, "Done.");
> ```

No it would not. The second parameter of `then` is the `onRejected` callback, not a string. You can't do that.

> My aim is to reduce the already ridiculous amount of code that
>   Promises generate.

Then use `async`/`await` syntax and a transpiler. It's as simple as

```
await Something(…);
console.log("Done");
```

> Does Bluebird have any method for this?

If you don't like to use a transpiler but are in an ES6 environment (like a recent Node.js), you can use generator functions to imitate `async`/`await` with [`Promise.coroutine`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html).

Answer (score 1):

That feature is pretty much exclusive to `setTimeout`. IE9 and below requires a polyfill for that anyway https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

The following would is a workaround for your example case using `console.log`. Be cautious using it with any function that references `this`. You can use `bind` to set the value of `this` or leave it `undefined`. Also, it will log the resolved value of the promise after "Done" due to the value being automatically passed as the last argument to `bind`.

```
Something( ... )
    .then(console.log.bind(undefined, "Done."));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi gave an excellent answer to your question. Just to add, if you use `() => console.log("Done.")` or some other general callback a lot, make it a separate function:

```
function afterSomething() {
  console.log("Done.");
}

Something( ... )
  .then(afterSomething);
```